# Rolling sum of shifted groupby not working on dataframe for first group entry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having an issue when trying to add a field to a `DataFrame` which sums the last three months (that is, not including this month).

I have a `DataFrame` which shows monthly fees, relating to `channel_id`:

```
+-------+---------+------------+----------+-------------------------+
| index |  date   | channel_id |   fee    |       NEW COLUMN        |
+-------+---------+------------+----------+-------------------------+
|    10 | 2018-03 |         22 | 24525.88 | (depends on rows above) |
|    11 | 2018-04 |         22 |    10493 | (depends on rows above) |
|    12 | 2018-05 |         22 |    12500 | (depends on rows above) |
|    13 | 2017-10 |         43 |     1000 | 0                       |
|    14 | 2017-11 |         43 |     1000 | 0                       |
|    15 | 2017-12 |         43 |     1000 | 0                       |
|    16 | 2018-01 |         43 |     1000 | 3000                    |
|    17 | 2018-02 |         43 |     1000 | 3000                    |
|    18 | 2018-03 |         43 |     1000 | 3000                    |
|    19 | 2018-04 |         43 |     1000 | 3000                    |
|    20 | 2018-05 |         43 |     1000 | 3000                    |
|    21 | 2017-10 |         58 |     1750 | 0                       |
|    22 | 2017-11 |         58 |     1750 | 0                       |
|    23 | 2017-12 |         58 |   3302.1 | 0                       |
|    .. | ..      |         .. |   ..     | ..                      |
+-------+---------+------------+----------+-------------------------+
```

For each channel_id, I want to aggregate the last 3 months fees.  The first three months for each channel_id (e.g. row indexes 4,5,6) should be 0, as there is not 3 prior months to sum.

In order to achieve this, I'm using:

`df.groupby(['channel_id']).rolling(3)[fee].sum().shift(1).sort_index(level=1).fillna(0)`

This *mostly* works, but for the first instance of *some* channel_ids, it populates a value that I can't tie to anything...:

```
+---------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
|  date   | channel_id |   fee    | NEW_COL  | Correct? |
+---------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2018-03 |         22 | 24525.88 | 52572.85 | YES      |
| 2018-04 |         22 |    10493 | 60211.76 | YES      |
| 2018-05 |         22 |    12500 | 53933.88 | YES      |
| 2017-10 |         43 |     1000 |     2400 | NO!!!    |
| 2017-11 |         43 |     1000 |        0 | YES      |
| 2017-12 |         43 |     1000 |        0 | YES      |
| 2018-01 |         43 |     1000 |     3000 | YES      |
| 2018-02 |         43 |     1000 |     3000 | YES      |
| 2018-03 |         43 |     1000 |     3000 | YES      |
| 2018-04 |         43 |     1000 |     3000 | YES      |
| 2018-05 |         43 |     1000 |     3000 | YES      |
| 2017-10 |         58 |     1750 |        0 | YES      |
| 2017-11 |         58 |     1750 |        0 | YES      |
| 2017-12 |         58 |   3302.1 |        0 | YES      |
+---------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

My understanding of the df operations is a bit sketchy, but my understanding of the chain is:

`df.groupby(['channel_id'])`: groups the data by the channel_id

`.rolling(3)[fee].sum()`: applies a rolling 3 month sum to the groupby dfs

`.shift(1)`: shifts the values up 1 (as we dont want the current month)

`.sort_index(level=1)`: Not sure exactly what this does in context, but it's required...

`.fillna(0)`: Fill NaNs with 0, where 3 previous months are not available.

I've played around with different sort_index values (and shift) but can't get my head around how this is working that incorrect value out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `apply`

```
df.groupby(['channel_id'])['fee'].apply(lambda x :x.rolling(3).sum().shift(1).fillna(0))
Out[319]: 
0        0.0
1        0.0
2        0.0
3        0.0
4        0.0
5        0.0
6     3000.0
7     3000.0
8     3000.0
9     3000.0
10    3000.0
11       0.0
12       0.0
13       0.0
Name: fee, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Notice : When there are more than one function you need to apply after groupby you need either do it with `apply` or two `groupby`

Answer (score 1):

I think need [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
df['new'] = (df.groupby(['channel_id']).rolling(3)['fee'].sum()
              .groupby(level=0)
              .shift(1)
              .sort_index(level=1)
              .fillna(0)
              .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
print (df)
          date  channel_id       fee  NEW COLUMN     new
index                                                   
10     2018-03          22  24525.88         NaN     0.0
11     2018-04          22  10493.00         NaN     0.0
12     2018-05          22  12500.00         NaN     0.0
13     2017-10          43   1000.00         0.0     0.0
14     2017-11          43   1000.00         0.0     0.0
15     2017-12          43   1000.00         0.0     0.0
16     2018-01          43   1000.00      3000.0  3000.0
17     2018-02          43   1000.00      3000.0  3000.0
18     2018-03          43   1000.00      3000.0  3000.0
19     2018-04          43   1000.00      3000.0  3000.0
20     2018-05          43   1000.00      3000.0  3000.0
21     2017-10          58   1750.00         0.0     0.0
22     2017-11          58   1750.00         0.0     0.0
23     2017-12          58   3302.10         0.0     0.0
```

Or maybe rolling by `4`:

```
df['new'] = (df.groupby(['channel_id']).rolling(4)['fee'].sum()
              .sort_index(level=1)
              .fillna(0)
              .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```